# Rewrite function in python - Optimized

Tags: python, function, optimization

Is there of a way to optimize this function?. The original version has more parameters inside the tuples, so it is unscalable with more if and elif.

```
from statistics import median

rule=[1,2,3]
direction=['up','down']

def function_db(mount,rule,direction):

        item=range(1,10)

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Porcentajes
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if rule==1 and direction == 'up' :
            final_item = min(item)*(1+mount/100)

        elif rule==2 and direction == 'up' :
            final_item = max(item)*(1+mount/100)

        elif rule==3 and direction == 'up' :
            final_item = median(item)*(1+mount/100)

        elif rule==1 and direction == 'down' :
            final_item = min(item)*(1-mount/100)

        elif rule==2 and direction == 'down' :
            final_item = max(item)*(1-mount/100)

        elif rule==3 and direction == 'down' :
            final_item = median(item)*(1-mount/100)

        return final_item


function_db(10,3,"up")
```

Comment: Inside what tuple?

Comment: Do you want it optimised for speed, readability, portability, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from statistics import median

rule=[1,2,3]
direction=['up','down']

def function_db(mount,rule,direction):
        dic={1:min,2:max,3:median}
        direct = {'up':1,'down':-1}
        item=range(1,10)
        final_item = dic[rule](item)*(1+(mount/100)*direct[direction])
        return final_item
```

Answer (score 1):

**Actually** this can even be a one-liner:

```py
def function_db(mount,rule,direction):
     items = [0, 9, 5]
     directions = {"up": 1, "down": -1}

     return items[rule-1]*(1+ directions[direction]*mount/100)
```

Comment: don't take the `items` and `directions` out of function, it might break up the code for further process written in main code where items and direction are written, better to maintain the encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to optimise the layout of the code (reducing the number of if-elses), but still maintaining readability.  I assume there's going to be many more rules than directions, so chose to put the rules into a list of functions.  So adding a new rule involves simply appending the function name into `rules`.

Obviously it's possible to factor-out some of the functionally-constant parts of the `multiplicand`, but I thought that greatly sacrificed readability.

I also thought it worthwhile to check for (and raise) errors.

```
from statistics import median

def function_db( mount, rule, direction ):

    item  = range( 1, 10 )
    rules = [ min, max, median ]

    if ( direction == 'up' ):
        multiplicand = ( 1+mount/100 )
    elif ( direction == 'down' ):
        multiplicand = ( 1-mount/100 )
    else:
        raise( ValueError( 'Unknown direction [' + str( direction ) + ']' ) )

    if ( rule == 0 or rule > len( rules ) ):
        raise( ValueError( 'Unknown rule-code [' + str( rule ) + ']' ) )


    # Compute the result
    multiplier = rules[ rule-1 ]( item )

    final_item = multiplier * multiplicand
    return final_item



print( "RESULT=%f" % ( function_db( 10, 3, "up" ) ) )
```